# regex to add a dash after specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings that look like the following as follows:

```
const strings = ['Prepayment', 'Postpayment', 'Complete']
const addDash = (str: string) =>
  str.startsWith('Pre') || str.startsWith('Post') ? str.replace(' ', '-') : str;
```

I want to have the following array:

```
const result = strings.map(str => addDash(str))
// => ['Pre-payment', 'Post-payment', 'Complete'] // want result to equal this
```

Can anyone advise what regex would help me to achieve this task?

Comment: You could do `str.replace("Pre", "Pre-")` and the same for Post

Comment: Can you provide more examples? Would you ever has `pretty` or similar strings?

Comment: @Norse i thought of that, but was hoping to be able to add them both into the same regex

Comment: But there is no space to replace in `'Prepayment'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should post that as an answer, explaining it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```js
const addDash = (str) => str.replace(/^P(?:re|ost)\B/, '$&-');

const strings = ['Prepayment', 'Postpayment', 'Complete']
const result = strings.map(str => addDash(str));
console.log(result);
```

The `^P(?:re|ost)\B` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `P(?:re|ost)` -  `Pre` or `Post`
- `\B` - followed with a word char.

`$&` is the backreference to the whole value matched with the regex.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9UZ08e/1).

Comment: Or also just `const result = strings.map(addDash);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this from perspective you have to add n+1 different strings and words that needs dashes. Here's my (hacky) solution:

```js
const getDashedStrings = (strings, regExps) => {
  return strings.map((singleString) => {
    let newString = singleString;
    regExps.forEach((rg, i) => {
      const dashedString = singleString.replace(rg, '$1-');
      if (dashedString !== singleString) {
        newString = dashedString;
      }
    });

    return newString;
  });
};
const getRegExps = (dashes) => dashes.map((word) => new RegExp(`(${word})`, 'gi'));

// ...

const strings1 = ['Prepayment', 'Postpayment', 'Complete']
const regExps1 = getRegExps(['Pre', 'Post']);

const strings2 = ['Frontend', 'COVID19'];
const regExps2 = getRegExps(['Front', 'COVID']);

console.log(getDashedStrings(strings1, regExps1));

console.log(getDashedStrings(strings2, regExps2));
```